# Adding some simple labels

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw, tikz-calc

Since I am a beginner with Tikz, I wanted to ask what is the best way to include labels to my lines, as in the picture:
[image]

This is the code:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west] {\small state 1};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east] {\small state 2};

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,4);

\draw [extended line=0.5cm, <->] (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M);                 
\draw [extended line=2.5cm, <->] ($(M)!0.5cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!0.5cm!90:(A)$);

\node [dot=$x^{*}$] at (M) {}; 
\fill [red] (M) circle [radius=2pt] ; 


\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use `pos` option, or `near end`, `very near end`, etc.

Comment: Missing `\documentclass[...]{...}` into your MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add something like `node[pos=0.9,right]{Payoff space $X$}` to the path.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
% \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta} % <-not used here

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west,font=\small] {state 1};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east,font=\small] {state 2};

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,4);

\draw [extended line=0.5cm, <->] (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{Payoff space $X$};                 
\draw [extended line=2.5cm, <->] ($(M)!0.5cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!0.5cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=2.25,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors};

\node [dot=right:$x^{*}$] at (M) {}; 
\fill [red] (M) circle [radius=2pt] ; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As for your additional question: here's a proposal. Please note that I dropped `extended line` from the second line since it makes things IHMO more complicated.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
% \usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows.meta} % <-not used here

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[dot/.style={circle,inner sep=1pt,fill,label={#1},name=#1},
  extended line/.style={shorten >=-#1,shorten <=-#1},
  extended line/.default=1cm]

\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4.5,0) node[anchor=north west,font=\small] {state 1};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4.5) node[anchor=south east,font=\small] {state 2};

\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (3,4);

\draw [extended line=0.5cm, <->] (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{Payoff space $X$};                 
\draw [ <->] ($(M)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!3cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors}
coordinate[pos=0.75] (x);
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0) -- (x);
\node [dot=right:$x^{*}$] at (M) {}; 
\fill [red] (M) circle [radius=2pt] ; 

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot. How can I make the text smaller?

Comment: @Nenne Just add e.g. `font=\small`, `\draw [extended line=0.5cm, <->] (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em,font=\small]{Payoff space $X$};                 
\draw [extended line=2.5cm, <->] ($(M)!0.5cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!0.5cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=2.25,right=1em,font=\small]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors};`

Comment: Thank you again. A further question, just to be sure of that: the package specifications such as \documentclass[...], \usepackage{tikz}, etc. should be set at the beginning of my whole document, or should be added whenever I start a new picture?

Comment: @Nenne They need to go to the preamble, i.e. you cannot add them after `\begin{document}`.

Comment: To be a little more clear, I started my document with the preamble \documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}. Should I add also \documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}?

Comment: @Nenne That's fine, as long as you add `\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} ` as you did it should work. Sebastiano was saying above that you should also add `\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}` to your code.

Comment: Ok! If I wanted also to add a vector starting at (0,0) up to a given point of the space of discount factors, how could it be added in my code?

Comment: @Nenne I added a proposal for that.

Comment: Ok, can I ask you how could I add a further vector starting at (0,0) up to another point of the space of discount factors?

Comment: @Nenne Just add more points along the line, e.g. with `coordinate[pos=0.4] (y)` and draw the line. i.e. replace `\draw [ <->] ($(M)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!3cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors}
coordinate[pos=0.75] (x);` by `\draw [<->] ($(M)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!3cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors}
coordinate[pos=0.75] (x) coordinate[pos=0.4] (y);
\draw[blue,-latex] (0,0) -- (y);`.

Comment: perfect!you helped me a lot!

Comment: May I ask you also how could I tell TikZ to make the line of the payoff space dashed just from $x^{*}$ onwards? And how could I shorten the same line? Thank you again for your patience.

Comment: @Nenne Replace `\draw [extended line=0.5cm, <->] (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{Payoff space $X$};` by `\path (A) -- (B) coordinate[midway] (M);
\draw [shorten >=-0.5cm, ->] (M) -- (A);
\draw [shorten >=-0.5cm, ->,dashed] (M) -- (B)
node[pos=0.95,right=1em]{Payoff space $X$};`, i.e. draw two separate lines.

Comment: Sorry, I wanted to do that on the perpendicular line. Can I use '\path' too?

Comment: @Nenne For that replace `\draw [ <->] ($(M)!3cm!270:(A)$) -- ($(M)!3cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors}
coordinate[pos=0.75] (x);` by `\draw [->,dashed] (M) -- ($(M)!3cm!90:(A)$)
node[pos=0.9,right=1em]{$m=x^*+\varepsilon$ space of discount factors}
coordinate[pos=0.5] (x);
\draw [ ->] (M) --($(M)!3cm!270:(A)$) ;`